# New puppet master VM counted towards licenses used, old puppet master node made agent no longer responsive

Tags: vmware-esxi, postgresql, puppet, puppetmaster, puppetdb

*Using VSphere Client 5.1 Ubuntu precise VM's with Puppet Enterprise 3.3.1 and PostgreSQL 9.3.1

I am utilizing the same postgresql database to manage a new puppet master and I know that the licenses are tied to the number of ssl certificates used, but what I am unsure about is if the data associated with keeping track of the number of ssl certificates generated and managed is handled in the postgresql database. Essentially I had a puppet master which I uninstalled in addition to a single puppet agent. Subsequently I installed a new puppet master on a separate VM and used the same postgresql databases/users/passwords and I expected to have my puppet console state only 1 license was used, but it seems to be 3 licenses despite having only one node (i.e. the previous master node is now an agent for the new master).

In addition, despite having a certificate accepted for my new agent which was formerly a master it seems to not be responsive despite waiting 30 minutes for a puppet run and also manually executing a puppet run.

Answer (score 0):

Have you revoked the certificate from the old server? If you run`puppet cert --list` on your master you should be able to see all of the valid puppet certs. You can then revoke the old one with `puppet cert --clean {node certname}` if you have a cert for a machine that no longer exists.